# Will my game work if its from Austraila to SA?

Tags: the-sims-4

Hello My aunty lives in Austraila and she wants to buy me the Sims 4. Now I live in south Africa and she is not sure if it will work! Thank you!

Comment: Work in what way?  Can you install Origin?

Answer (score 2):

If your aunt will buy you the game, she will either get:

- The boxed retail version, from a shop for example. These boxes contain the CD, but also a keycode. This keycode can be then reedemed on the Origin Store using your account.
- Buy the keycode from an online site like gamersgate or greenmangaming
- Buy the game while using your Origin account from the Origin Store. That will link the game to your account permanently.

All of the options above require you to have a valid and new game keycode or to be logged in with your account, **so yes you should be able to play it fine**.

I bought the game at a reduced price from the official Mexican Origin store from a PC in Europe. It works perfectly and once registered to my origin account, I was able to install it from Origin (in english even).

Keep in mind: if you buy a game from a country that had the game censored in any way (such as Half-Life or Fallout: New Vegas in Germany) you'll get the censored version even if you will play it in some other country with no censored restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

EA's Terms and Conditions don't say anything about the game being restricted by region, and, according to an [entry](http://answers.ea.com/t5/The-Sims-4/Is-Sims-4-region-locked/td-p/3546783) on EA's help forum, you should be able to play it without a problem.